# How do I implement Floating Action Button in iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin

Please tell me how to implement Floating Action Button(FAB) in iOS. I have seen this link jamesmontemagno/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android and could able to do it in Android. Please tell me the code to implement it in iOS.
Environment: Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar free component in the Xamarin Store for Xamarin.iOS and a Nuget Library for Xamarin.Forms

[Liquid Floating Action Button for Xamarin.iOS](https://components.xamarin.com/view/liquidfloatingactionbutton)

[Floating Action Button For Xamarin.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FAB.Forms/)

Comment: This is particularly for IOS. What I need is in Xamarin.Forms. So I should be able to create a custom renderer class in IOS and could be able to use that control in Xamarin PCL in such a way, used by jamesmontemagno https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android. Any idea on how to create that?

Comment: @BissyVarghese Check the Nuget Library i have added a link to it. Its for Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

Checkout link for implementing Floating Action Button in IOS. 
[github Library](https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton)

Comment: This is particularly for IOS. What I need is in Xamarin.Forms. So I should be able to create a custom renderer class in IOS and could be able to use that control in Xamarin PCL in such a way, used by jamesmontemagno https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/FloatingActionButton-for-Xamarin.Android. Any idea on how to create that?

Answer (score -2):

use VCFloatingActionButton cocoa.
for even better animation while button hides the menu, use the code below.

```
-(void) dismissMenu:(id) sender

{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationTime / 2 animations:^{
        self.pressedImageView.alpha = 0.0f;
        self.pressedImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
        self.normalImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
        self.normalImageView.alpha = 1.0f;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

            [self.bgView setAlpha:1.0f];
            NSMutableArray* arrayIndexpath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            while (noOfRows > 0) {
                noOfRows -= 1;
                NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:noOfRows inSection:0];
                [arrayIndexpath addObject:indexPath];
            }
            [_menuTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayIndexpath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [_menuTable reloadData];

        }
            completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{

                    [self.bgView setAlpha:0.0f];

                }
                                 completion:nil];

            }];

    }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){

        }];
}
```